# What is the terminology for this Java code structure?

Tags: java

I have been using this more frequently now in Java but I don't know what it is called.  Essentially there is a function which takes a type as a param and within the function there are overridden functions/methods that can be used.  These functions can be executed within functions that are exposed by the main class.  For example:

```
public class Whatisthis {

    private OtherLibsomeCallback theCallback;

    public void dothatthang{

        //What do you call this kind of code structure?
        someCallback(window, theCallback = new OtherLibsomeCallback() {

            @Override
            public void invoke(long a, double b) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                globalVar = a + b;
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: "Anonymous class".  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html.

Comment: `inner class` or to be more specific `Anonymous class` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called as the `Anonymous` class.

This is from the Oracle docs:

`Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not  have a name.`

Comment: Thank you.  I'll do some reading - now that I know what to look for.  I find this Anonymous class very clean and useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can say it short hand coding techniques.

The code is using `Anonymous class` as argument to function.

Answer (score 0):

This Is **Anonymous inner class**

which can be declare in several ways. its mostly use when you want to override some feature of base class/interface (mostly **abstract class/ interface**). its giving pure inheritance feature. and its also   declared and instantiated at the same time as @Abhishek said.

you can also use anonymous inner class in method's call as :

```
object.someMethod(new Object(){
    // you can override method here
  });
```